# Simplify multiple functions into one in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, text, append

I am wondering how it is possible to combine the following functions into one. The functions remove the entire word if "_" respectively "/" occur in a text.

I have tried the following, and the code fulfils it purpose. It his however cumbersome and I am wondering how to simplify it.

```
text = "This is _a default/ text"
def filter_string1(string):
    a = []
    for i in string.split():
        if "_" not in i:
            a.append(i)
    return ' '.join(a)
def filter_string2(string):
    a = []
    for i in string.split():
        if "/" not in i:
            a.append(i)
    return ' '.join(a)

text_no_underscore = filter_string1(text)
text_no_underscore_no_slash = filter_string2(text_no_underscore)
print(text_no_underscore_no_slash)
```

The output is (as desired):

"This is text"

Comment: you could edit the if condtion to ```if "_" not in i and "/" not in i:```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the if conditions.

```
text = "This is _a default/ text"

def filter(string):
    a = []
    for i in string.split():
        if "_" not in i and "/" not in i:
            a.append(i)
    return ' '.join(a)

print(filter(text))
```

Comment: thank you for this quick and easy solution, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) in python's [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module which will let you accomplish this quickly.

```
def remove_words(text):
    import re
    return re.sub(
        pattern=r'\s_[\s\S^\/]*\/',  # regular expression used to match the parts to remove
        repl='',                     # replace matched parts with empty string
        string=text                  # use `text` as input
    )
```

Explaining the regular expression `\s_[\s\S^\/]*\/` (by deconstructing its parts):

- `\s_` match whitespace character followed by underscore
- `[\s\S^\/]*` match any character sequence not containing a forward slash (sequence may be length 0)
- `\/` match the forward slash

Testing the function:

```
text = "This is _a default/ text"
text_no_underscore_no_slash = remove_words(text)
print('Result:', text_no_underscore_no_slash)
# Result: This is text

text = "This is _a longer/ _and also custom/ text"
text_no_underscore_no_slash = remove_words(text)
print('Result:', text_no_underscore_no_slash)
# Result: This is text
```

By the way, your original code has a bug, I think.

```
text = "This is _a longer/ _and also custom/ text"
text_no_underscore = filter_string1(text)
text_no_underscore_no_slash = filter_string2(text_no_underscore)
print(text_no_underscore_no_slash == 'This is text')
# False
```